# Blank page comes in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I found a blank page after login while same code working in other contriller.
I think session not working so that redirect also not working i'm using this code for session and rediction

```
$this->Session->write('Adm.id', $result['Adm']['id']);
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Adms', 'action' => 'home'));
```

Comment: check if there is any error on your home action which is causing cake to render a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Something that commonly blocks sessions and will cause a blank page is the write permissions where the session is writing. If you are using files for session management, check the permissions on the directory where your session data is being written.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same bug.
Check your AppController and others Controller (and the models) :

- look for an empty line at the end of your file

Not good :

```
Line 1  class UsersController extends AppController {
Line 2     //your code
Line 9  }
Line 10 *Delete this line*
```

Comment: you can have 10k blank lines after a class if you like, just don't use `?>` in php files.